# Missing pand command: which package does it belong to?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to setup a PAN through Bluetooth with my Raspberry Pi 3.
Many guides available on the internet suggest to use the `pand` command but whenever I run it I receive a `command not found` error, probably because the package which it belongs to is not installed.

I tried to `apt-get install` both `bluez-utils` and `bluez-compat` but they do not seem to be available. What package do I have to install?

Has it been obsoleted and been replaced by a new command?

Comment: I believe pand was deprecated a decade ago.  You probably have to use Network Manager nowadays.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Do you mean wicd? Is't only for wlan and eth interfaces?

Comment: No, I'm thinking of a GUI called Network Manager.  I'm not sure what the underlying program is called.  You will need to wait until someone more familiar with bluetooth and networking sees your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Anyway, knowing that pand is "officially" deprecated has been helpful, I'll now look for different solutions.

Comment: `a decade ago` You guys must be old. @joan

Comment: Were you able to find an alternate to using `pand`?